# Как реализовать интерфейс в C++?

Tags: c++, интерфейс

Каким образом реализовываются интерфейсы в C++? Я много программирую на golang и для меня интерфейс в golang -- это контракт, который предоставляется как публичное API. Каким образом это реализовывается в c++? Абстрактные классы?

Пример интерфейса в `golang`

```
type Contract interface {
    func MyMethod() int 
}


func Run(obj Contract) int {
    return obj.MyMethod() + 1
}
```

В данном случае, я создал контракт `Contract`, который использую в `Run`. В `Run` я могу передать любой объект, который удовлетворяет контракту, т.е. имеет соответствующий метод

Comment: уточните, что за интерфейс. Интерфейс пользователя, интерфейс с системой и т.д

Comment: @maint Интерфейс для системы. Ровно так, как это понимается, в golang. Т.е. как я пишу, это должен быть контракт, который, например, фиксирует сигнатуры методов.

Comment: наверное шаблоны ближе к интерфейсам го. абстрактные классы - это больше про наследование.

Comment: @goldstar_labs кажется, что в java есть аналогичные golang интерфейсы. Шаблоны -- это точно про другое. Шаблоны -- это про параметризацию типов. B golang это решается с помощью генерации кода

Comment: приведите пример интерфейса в го)

Comment: @goldstar_labs добавил

Comment: Через Чисто абстрактные классы у которых все методы публичны и объявлены так: `virtual <some type> method(<some args>) = 0;`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, точно. Я тоже ща на это набрёл. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void Printer(const T& object)
{
    object.print();
}

class Printable
{
public:
    void print() const { std::cout << "Hello from Printable" << std::endl; }
};

class NonPrintable
{
public:
    void not_print() const { std::cout << "Hello from NonPrintable" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Printable o1;
    NonPrintable o2;

    Printer(o1);
    Printer(o2); // error C2039: 'print': is not a member of 'NonPrintable'

    return 0;
}
```

> В Run я могу передать любой объект, который удовлетворяет контракту,
>   т.е. имеет соответствующий метод

По аналогии с вашим, в данном примере шаблонная функция `Printer` может быть вызвана для любых типов, у которых определен метод `print()`.

Comment: Всё-таки, видится мне, что шаблоны -- это про другое. Я, кажется, нашёл `virtual`. Почитаю

Comment: @hedgehogues virtual это про изменение реализации метода в производном классе, видимо я не так понимаю пример из го)